# Cómo ocultar menú responsivo, al momento de disminuir dimensiones de pantalla (smartphone)

Tags: html, css, html5, bootstrap, frontend

tengo un típico panel de administración con su menú lateral izquierdo funcionando todo ok, es responsivo y demás. El tema es que al momento de diminuir la dimensión de la pantalla, ya sea a una resolución de smartphone, el menú se sigue mostrando y me tapa gran parte del contenido, debo presionar en el botón para quitarlo y quede una vista mejor pero mi idea es ahcerlo automático.

```html
<ul class="navbar-nav bg-gradient-primary sidebar sidebar-dark accordion" id="accordionSidebar">
```

Como se aprecia en el código de arriba, actualmente así se muestra completo el menú lateral izquierdo. Pero...

```html
<ul class="navbar-nav bg-gradient-primary sidebar sidebar-dark accordion toggled" id="accordionSidebar">
```

Si en el código le agrego **"toggled"** se cierra hacia la izquierda y queda mejor la visualización. Cómo podría hacer para que en el tamaño normal de pc quede como en el primer código "sin el toggled" y cuando disminuyo el tamaño a smartphone o X dimensión quede oculto agregándole el "toggled" a la etiqueta ul? existe alguna validación que se pueda realizar? muchas gracias por su aporte!!!

Comment: necesitamos mas detalles pues tu codigo no muestra nada, en todo caso podrias acerlo con js pero aun asi hace falta mas  detalles

Comment: Puedes usar JS y CSS para controlar estos temas, te invito a desarrollar un poco más la consulta para tener claridad de que es lo que estas realizando y que es lo que requieres, de esta forma te podremos dar una mejor respuesta.